# Raspberr Pi 2 with Windows 10 IoT Core as A2DP Sink

Tags: c#, bluetooth, win-universal-app, windows-10-iot-core

I want to create a headless UWP app for the Raspberry Pi 2 which acts as a sink for A2DP audio and outputs the audio on the speakers connected to the audio jack of the raspberry.

I cannot find any samples, how to achive this. Is this possible in the current Windows IoT Core release and where can I find some samples or infos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 10 IoT Core doesn't currently support the A2DP Bluetooth profile so this probably isn't possible.  A list of the supported profiles can be found here: https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/Bluetooth.htm